# Using Output() and EventEmitter() to Pass Value in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, eventemitter

Last week I managed to get Output() and EventEmitter() working in my Angular app. But today I'm running into a problem in trying to implement this in another scenario. Not sure what I'm missing.

First off, in a sub-component that handles filters that are applied to a list of records I have this:

```
@Output() sendFilter = new EventEmitter();

optionClicked(option) {
    this.sendFilter.emit(option);
    console.log('Filter from filters comp is: ' + option.toolbarLabel);
    this.option = option;
}
```

The view for this filter component looks like this:

```
<md-checkbox *ngFor="let option of categoryFilters.options" 
   [(ngModel)]="option.value" (click)="optionClicked(option)">
   {{option.label}}
</md-checkbox>
```

So I am using "sendFilter" to emit "option". Then, in my other component, I assume this value should be received/pass into this function:

```
optionReceived(option) {
    console.log('Consulting: ' + option.toolbarLabel);
}
```

In the view for this component I have this:

```
<list-display [records]="records" (sendChange)="pageChange($event)" (sendFilter)="optionReceived(option)"></list-display>
```

However, only the event on the filter component logs to the console. The console.log I have right above here never happens. Shouldn't that "optionReceived()" function trigger automatically upon a new emit from the filter component?

I even tried adding "optionClicked(option)" to Angular's OnChanges life cycle hook:

```
ngOnChanges(option) {
    this.optionReceived(option.toolbarLabel);
}
```

... But still nothing logs to the console from that component.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your checkbox is inside the sub-component and you should be using as below

Mistake 1:

```
@Output() sendFilter = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Mistake 2:

```
<sub-component (sendFilter)="optionReceived($event)"> </sub-component>
```

Implementing this method in yourparent component as

```
optionReceived(option:any){
        console.log('Consulting: ' + option.toolbarLabel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize part of the complexity here is that I am passing from one component, to a view component, and then down to another component. So it's like a three step process. Do I therefore need two Outputs and EventEmitters - for each time the event is passed down, or is there a different way to handle this?

Comment: Yup. if you want to avoid using more output and input you can go for state management techniques

Comment: Thanks! Got it working now. Just to clarify, the issue came down to not having this <sub-component (sendFilter)="optionReceived($event)"> </sub-component>, and not realizing I needed to pass the Output and EventEmitter two times. Not sure why you listed the first @Output item as a "mistake"? Did you mean that could be the potential problem?

Comment: Aravind I was wondering if you could comment on my issue [How to create component dynamically with @Output EventEmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932287/how-to-create-component-dynamically-with-output-eventemitter#)

Comment: @dak I'm not able to understand what you are trying to do there in that post!! I will be gald to help you